# Special merit of the keeper of the Ark of the Covenant

Tags: samuel-shmuel-book-of, ark-aron-kodesh

In [*Shmuel* 1, chapter 6](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15835#), the *Plishtim* returned the Ark of the Covenant back to the Jews, and it rested on a big stone in the field of Joshua from *Beis Shemesh* (verse 14).

What was the special merit of Joshua that he deserved that the Ark would be placed in his territory?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10630/967